# In a principal component space, is a change in any coordinate going to result in the same distance between PC-projected observations?

Tags: pca, distance

Suppose that we have observations in a 2-dimensional principal coordinate space. Let's denote one observation $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2)$ in our PC space. Further, suppose that we have another observation $\mathbf{y}'=(y_1',y_2')$. Consider two scenarios:

1. $y_1'=y_1$, $y_2' = y_2 + c,$
2. $y_1' = y_1 + c$, $y_2'=y_2,$

where $c$ is the same constant in both scenarios. Am I correct in assuming that both scenarios result in the same distance between $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{y}'$?

Or, are some PCs more important than others? i.e., a change in one coordinate results in a more significant change between observations than a change in another coordinate

Comment: What distance metric are you using in your "PC space"?  Because PCs are supposed to be rotations of the data and rotations preserve distances, one would think that you are asking about the original Euclidean metric for the data.  But if you are scaling your coordinates, then perhaps you are asking about the Mahalanobis distance?

Comment: @whuber I am asking about the original squared Euclidean distance. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Orthogonal transformations, by definition, do not change the distance.